# Ionic ion-select, ion-select-option

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have create a new project ionic with capacitor. I use use ion-select, but i have i new ion-select-option with(by) large text, not distriute in input.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label class="my-label" position="stacked">Plaga/Enfermedad</ion-label>
  <ion-select >
    <ion-select-option value="Alternaria, Mancha marrón de las mandarinas (primavera)">Alternaria, Mancha marrón de las mandarinas (primavera)
    </ion-select-option>

  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

How to change this properties for view all text.
show my image

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your help.  I try this way it´s work
// ionic 6 version

```
ion-select::part(text) {
    white-space: normal !important;
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display all your text inside the `ion-select`, you can use the `ion-text-wrap` class on your `ion-select-option`. This class is provided by Ionic CSS utilities (https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities). Your code shoud look like this :

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label class="my-label" position="stacked">Plaga/Enfermedad</ion-label>
  <ion-select >
    <ion-select-option class="ion-text-wrap" value="Alternaria, Mancha marrón de las mandarinas (primavera)">Alternaria, Mancha marrón de las mandarinas (primavera)
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**EDIT :** It seems that the `ion-text-wrap` class does not wrap the text in the `ion-select` textbox. Since this element is in the shadowroot, you need to use some javascript to apply style dynamically.

So you need to first give an #id to your `ion-select` component and add a callback to the `(ionChange)` event :

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-label class="my-label" position="stacked">Plaga/Enfermedad</ion-label>
    <ion-select (ionChange)="editShadowStyle()" id="my-select">
        <ion-select-option value="Alternaria, Mancha marrón de las mandarinas (primavera)">Alternaria,
            Mancha
            marrón de las
            mandarinas (primavera)
        </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Then, in your typescript file, define this function :

```
editShadowStyle() {
    let textbox = document
      .getElementById("my-select")
      .shadowRoot.querySelector("div");
    textbox.setAttribute("style", "white-space:pre-line");
}
```

This way, each time you will select an option in the `ion-select`, the shadowroot element style will be edited. Please see result below : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-fztn1b?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your helpful but the same result, the text is crop

Comment: @ProgramaClases please see my edit above, I found a workaround